# Iteratively Create Dataset Using rvest

Tags: r, rvest

I am pretty new to R, but I am really interested in learning how to use it (specifically the new package rvest) in order to screen scrape information from articles for research papers, etc.

I want to create a dataset of all the ratings and directors of movies on IMDB.  I have the code that can get ONE rating at a time:

```
library(rvest)
HG_Movie <- html("http://www.imdb.com/title/tt01781922")
score <- HG_Movie %>%
    html_node("strong span") %>%
    html_text() %>%
    as.numeric()
print(score)
```

That will work and I print the score at the end to make sure it is correct (6.9)

So, now, the hard part.  I want to be able to iterate over many imdb pages and collect the rating and the name of the director as well, and I want these to be written into a dataset of some type (doesn't matter if it is .csv or .txt or whatever).  The finishing dataset would look something like:

```
Title Score Director
XX    YY    HH
AA    BB    CC
```

and so on.  It would be amazing to learn to do this both with a list of all the urls, or wihtout, using some sort of loop over a certain range of values. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should probably just download the plaintext data files instead of scraping their pages. http://www.imdb.com/interfaces

Comment: Hey Bill,  I was hoping to be able to use this package for more serious and difficult to parse websites that may not provide those data files.  I was just using this as a place to start so I can get an understanding of how the package works before expanding to harder things.